# Count occurrence of a Column's entity in a Data Frame using R

Tags: r

**What I need:**
How many times values of a particular column repeats.

```
df <- Route1 Route2 Route3 Route4
       a       b      c      a
       d       c      a      k
       e       c      b      c
       c       a      a      b
```

Now I wish to count how many times values of Route4(including Route4) comes.
The expected result is :

```
  Ans  <- Route1 Route2 Route3 Route4   Count
            a       b      c      a       2       #as a has come 2 times
            d       c      a      k       1       #as k has come 1 times
            e       c      b      c       2       #as c has come 2 times
            c       a      a      b       1       #as b has come 1 times
```

Any package or direct approach is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `apply`:
We can look for `Route4` column data in each row and measure its `length`.

```
df$count <- apply(df, 1, function(x) length(which(x==x[4])))
```

Output:

```
    Route1 Route2 Route3 Route4 count
1      a      b      c      a     2
2      d      c      a      k     1
3      e      c      b      c     2
4      c      a      a      b     1
```

Comment: Thanks Saurabh Chauhan it worked. Can you further tell me if column's count =2 then Y, else N in Another column (like df$Ananlysis)

Comment: @Adi.sr: Try this `df$Analysis <- ifelse(df$count==2,'Y','N')`

Comment: how can I make 'A' and 'a' same. Because above code differentiate them as two different and change the count.

Comment: @Adi.sr: You can convert all letters to lower case or upper case and apply the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowSums`. Notice that all the columns need to be in character, not in factor.

```
df$count <- rowSums(df == df$Route4)

df
#   Route1 Route2 Route3 Route4 count
# 1      a      b      c      a     2
# 2      d      c      a      k     1
# 3      e      c      b      c     2
# 4      c      a      a      b     1
```

**DATA**

```
df <- read.table(text = "Route1 Route2 Route3 Route4
       a       b      c      a
       d       c      a      k
       e       c      b      c
       c       a      a      b",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```